# In multi record form how to set focus on 5th record when new form instance in Oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

In Oracle 10g forms developer i have 2 forms one is search form another is details.details form is multi record form.wgen details form opens cursor points to first record by default.(out of 10 records in forms).we have a requirement where if TRX number in search form on populate details if is on position 5th in details form then cursor should point to 5th position record.how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "TRX number" is, but - a simple option is to use a built-in procedure:

```
go_block('your_detail_block');
go_record(:trx_number_field);
```

---

Another option is to use a loop:

```
go_block('your_detail_block');
for i in 1 .. :trx_number_field loop
  next_record;
end loop;
```

Comment: I have tried next record in loop but it opens new form insted of going to 2nd record

Comment: That's pretty much impossible, because NEXT_RECORD navigates to next record; it doesn't open a new form. Is there any other trigger that causes it (as as consequence of programatically navigating to a new record)?

Comment: Yes ..details block has multiple triggers as- post query,post select,keynxtblk,pre-record,query find,on populate details. And i have tried loop in on-populate-details trigger

Comment: OK, so check which one opens a new form. By the way, NEXT-RECORD is a restricted procedure; you can't call it from *every* trigger. Read more about it in Forms Help.

Comment: Is there any way how can we implement this in on-populate-details trigger?

Comment: Yes, as it allows restricted built-ins. See edited answer; I forgot (as I developed Forms applications quite a while ago) that there's a simpler and more efficient procedure you can use: **GO_RECORD**.

Comment: NO_DATA_FOUND is raised by some SELECT statement. Debug the form; it is pretty much useless trying to *guess* what's wrong, you're just wasting time.